# Float addition not including decimal c++

Tags: c++, double, decimal

Im trying to do an elipsoid and to do so I need the following operation

```
float result = this->eValues[0]+this->eValues[2]-this->eValues[1]
```

in this case

```
eValues[0]=-1.86265e-09;
eValues[1]=8.999999;
eValues[2]=8.999999;
```

It supposed it should return -1.86265e-09 but the result is 0

Thanks

Comment: please define `get`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh result of the operation

Comment: and how do you check that?

Comment: @SouravGhosh using cout

Comment: What is `eValues` declared as?  An `int`?  It should be `float` (or `double`).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm they are float

Comment: Can't reproduce it. http://ideone.com/OcVkgH

Comment: What is your compiler, your machine, and how are you compiling this?

Comment: cannot reproduce it too (g++ 4.6.3), maybee you could try to use std::setprecision ?
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/

Comment: g++ ubuntu 14,04 using terminal g++ -o o *.cxx @asimes

Comment: What's your hardware platform?  Are floats 2 bytes (16 bits)?  Or maybe your FPU is defective.

Comment: update the question with other values here the code its result is 0

Comment: http://ideone.com/mIrlyG @RSahu

Answer (score 7):

This is a problem of floating point precision, it is made more clear by the order that the additions is carried out:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
        float a = -1.86265e-09;
        float b = 8.999999;
        float c = 8.999999;
        std::cout << ((a + b) - c) << std::endl; // 0
        std::cout << (a + (b - c)) << std::endl; // -1.86265e-09
        return 0;
}
```

The reason why the first output produces 0 is because `-1.86265e-09` is very small relative to `8.999999`. The difference in the exponent of how floating point numbers is stored is too great for the float to produce the correct arithmetic answer